# How to check where .NET ConfigurationManager is looking for a .config file?

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

I'm building a plugin assembly and I would like to provide an accompanying config file.

Deployed assembly is probably copied somewhere, don't know where, and would like to know where does the ConfigurationManager looks for a .config file. I do not wish to load .config from an explicit location, just put it where it is being looked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple: it looks in the directory where the .exe is stored for an appname.exe.config file.  That makes it unsuitable for your intended use.

Comment: I do not have a an exe, it's a plugin assembly used by another process. Putting a config beside the assembly does not help.

But if I understood you correctly it won't be loaded, unless I load it explicitly. Correct?

Comment: @HansPassant: Isn't it possible to have the CM look in different places via OpenExeConfiguration etc? It should be possible to specify a config file for a plugin, too (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [procmon from sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor file activity and see where it tries to open the file.